# Check whether the following is a metric

Tags: metric-spaces

I got this question on an internal today,

Check whether

$e(x,y)$ = $d(f(x),f(y))$ for any function $f:X \rightarrow X$ is a metric on $(X,d)$.

I think that I have messed it up.

My argument was that, because the identity map is always injective therefore it should be a metric.

But apparently some of my classmates thought otherwise, so i have become a little doubtful of my argument. Could someone tell me whether i am right or not ?

Comment: HINT: Is it an isometry? Does the function preserve distance? Check for this. WE ARE NOT TELLING YOU THE ANSWER WITHOUT WORK.

Comment: @DonLarynx: Let's assume $d(x,y)$ is known to be a metric.  By definition if $f$ were an isometry, then $e(x,y)=d(f(x),f(y))$ would be the *same* metric.  But this is not necessary to conclude $e(x,y)$ is a metric, so it may not be the best hint for checking the general case.

Comment: The general case asks whether "any function $f$" will give a metric $e(x,y)$.  Instead of checking the identity function, think about a function such that $f(x)=f(y)$ for $x\neq y$.

Comment: @hardmath So do you mean that "f" need not necessarily be injective ?

Comment: @hardmath Alright, after reading your comment again, i have realized that probably my argument is actually not correct.

Comment: @hardmath How do you check it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is *not* always true that for any function $f$ from metric space $(X,d)$ to itself that:

$$ e(x,y) = d(f(x),f(y)) $$

will also be a metric.  The simplest counterexample would be if $f$ is not injective, say $f(x)=f(y)$ for some $x\neq y$.  Then $e(x,y) = 0$ but this contradicts the property of a metric that having zero distance implies equality of two points.

The question of which maps $f$ will give us a metric $e(x,y)$ is an interesting one.  The above shows $f$ must be injective, a necessary condition.  If $f$ were an isometry, then by definition $e(x,y)=d(x,y)$ gives back the *same* metric, a sufficient condition.   In between these extremes there are other possibilities to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $D(x,y) \to D[i(x), i(y)]$ Is this an isometry?

HINT: Where does the identity function map elements to?

Comment: i believe it is an isometry.The metric should be preserved under the identity map.

Comment: @DonLarynx Sorry but this is not pointing the OP in the right direction.

Comment: @DonLarynx My argument was that, because the identity map is always injective therefore it should be a metric.But apparently some of my classmates thought otherwise, so i have become a little doubtful of my argument. Could you tell me whether i am right or not ?